# IOS9 how to find differences between two CNContact?

Tags: ios, swift, contacts

I was trying to manipulate contacts via new framework Contacts and ContactsUI on IOS9. I need find out the exact differences after end user change their information such as phone numbers or emails, that is, find out what the end user did on their address book for specified contact.

It's easier if the contact has different label for each item (phones/emails). However, I don't know how to fetch the differences if there are same label for phones or emails, e.g.:

John:
  phone:
    home: 123-456
    office: 223-456
    office: 456-334
  email:
    email: 124@email.com
    email: 345@google.com

after changed, the new information can be:
John:
  phone:
    home: 123-456
    office: 223-889 (changed item)
    office: 456-377 (changed item)
  email:
    email: 1241111@email.com (changed item)
    email: 3451111@google.com (changed item)

With ContactsUI, I can capture the two contact objects before change and after change.

The question is, how to find the changes?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Go through the properties and compare them?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you know how to iterate through array of new `phoneNumbers` and `emails` and old ones. You can compare pairs of label & value between old and new contact object, and determine whether a new pair was existed.

Some untested code:

```
func findOutContactDifference() {
  // Assume you already have the two contact objects
  let oldContact : CNContact = ...
  let newContact : CNContact = ...

  // Get list of phoneNumbers out
  let oldPhoneNumbers = oldContact.phoneNumbers
  let newPhoneNumbers = newContact.phoneNumbers

  // Iterate through the new phoneNumbers array
  for aNewPhoneNumber in newPhoneNumbers { // Type of aNewPhoneNumber will be CNLabeledValue
    let newPhoneLabel = aNewPhoneNumber.label // This will be a string
    let newPhoneNumber = aNewPhoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber // You have to cast as specified in the document

    let thisPhoneNumberAlreadyExisted = phoneNumberExisted(newPhoneLabel, newNumber : newPhoneNumber, oldPhoneNumbers : oldPhoneNumbers)
    if (!thisPhoneNumberAlreadyExisted) {
      // This is a new phone number!!
      let brandNewNumber = newPhoneNumber
    }
  }

  // Do the similar thing for email
  // Beaware that cast for email.value will just be String
  // ...
}

/// Will return whether the input pair already existed in the old list
func phoneNumberExisted(newLabel : String, newNumber : CNPhoneNumber, oldPhoneNumbers : [CNLabeledValue]) -> Bool {
  for anOldPhoneNumber in oldPhoneNumbers {
    let oldLabel = anOldPhoneNumber.label
    let oldNumber = anOldPhoneNumber.value as! CNPhoneNumber

    if oldLabel == newLabel && oldNumber == newLabel {
      return true // Found a matched pair
    }
  }
  return false // Nothing matched
}
```

==========

Reference for `CNLabeledValue` `value` property

> A contact property value, such as CNPhoneNumber for a phone number, NSString for an email address, and so on. For valid values, see CNContact properties that are arrays of labeled value objects.

**EDIT**

Reference for `CNLabeledValue` `identifier` property

> It is recommended that you use the identifier when searching for a previously known labeled value object in a re-fetched contact. The identifier can be **persisted** between the app launches.

Comment: Hi zcui93, Thanks for your reply but in some cases the labels are always the same for example the contacts who imported from outlook.com account. So the label + number pairs cannot work well..

Comment: Comparing all combinations will ensure that you will not miss any matching.  The reason we are using a pair is that the label on its own doesn't work. You may give examples that you think won't work. In the example in gave in the question, "home: 123-456" will be identified as unchanged, and all others will be identified as changed.

Comment: you are right, with your code we can find the changed items. But for further information, for instance, if I need trace the change, from which number changed to another number, it's far more difficult to get it cause there are duplicated labels. Am I correct?

Comment: With IOS, people can add the new phone number, delete, or change the phone label. I almost got crazy on capturing this changes... any idea? maybe I will have to make my own UI...

Comment: You will capture all these changes by comparing pairs. What's wrong/

Comment: e.g.  before changed, home: 123-456 office: 223-456 office: 456-334, after changed, home: 123-456 office: 556-444. Now my confusion is, how can I capture that which number is deleted, and which is changed to "office: 556-444"?   Appreciated for your help..

Comment: Ok, if you _really_ want to differentiate two offices, you should use `identifier` property of `CNLabeledValue`. But I think for most real life cases, you just want to capture what's the new number/email, and remove  all old changed values.